# Add a Label to Gmail using the Ruby Gmail API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a new label in my Gmail account using the Ruby Gmail API.

I have a working connection and can access my messages, list labels, etc.

However, when I try to use [create_user_label](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/google-api-client/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/service.rb#L474) I get the following error.

```
Google::Apis::ClientError: invalidArgument: Invalid request
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:218:in 'check_status'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:116:in 'check_status'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:183:in 'process_response'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:299:in 'execute_once'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in 'block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:61:in 'block in retriable'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:57:in 'times'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:57:in 'retriable'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:101:in 'block in execute'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:61:in 'block in retriable'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:57:in 'times'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:57:in 'retriable'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:93:in 'execute'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:360:in 'execute_or_queue_command'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/google-api-client-0.19.1/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/service.rb:543:in 'create_user_label'
/Users/brianrhea/Sites/myproject/lib/tasks/gmail_api.rake:47:in 'block in <top (required)>'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in '<top (required)>'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
/Users/brianrhea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'
```

My failing code in that stack trace is:

```
client = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
client.authorization = current_user.Token.fresh_token
user_id = 'me'

label = {
  "label_list_visibility" => "labelShow",
  "message_list_visibility" => "show",
  "name" => "TestLabel"
}

client.create_user_label(user_id, label)
```

The API's code in `create_user_label` calls for a [label_object](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/google-api-client/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/classes.rb#L513) which I thought I was creating.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [inline docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/google-api-client/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/service.rb#L474) say you need to use a object of type `Google::Apis::GmailV1::Label` as your `label_object`:

> @param [Google::Apis::GmailV1::Label] label_object

See if changing your `label` variable from a hash to this works:

```
label = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Label.new({
  name: 'TestLabel',
  label_list_visibility: 'labelShow',
  message_list_visibility: 'show',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Label.new({
   name: 'Label Name',
   label_list_visibility: 'labelShow',
   message_list_visibility: 'show',
   color: { background_color: "#fb4c2f", text_color: "#000000" 
  }
 })
```

With colours